# GCDAsyncSocket readDataWithTimeout and didReadData are truncating incoming data strings larger than 1460 bytes (1 packet)

Tags: ios, gcdasyncsocket

My iOS app is using GCDAsyncSocket to receive data from a server.  The server is collecting external data once per minute.  The app periodically connects to the server, and receives this data.  The server keeps track of what has been sent, so each minute's data will only be sent once.  The server is only keeping the last hour of data. Each minute of data is a string of around 100 bytes (+/- 20 bytes).

The string is received, separated into minutes, and each minute is separated in to the various quantities in each minute of data.

If the app has not connected to the server for over one hour, the app will download 60 minutes worth of data.   When this happens, I only get about 15 minutes of data.  I tracked this down to the fact that the method readDataWithTimeout only loads one packet on the readQueue, which limits me to 1460 bytes.  I've found that when I add a second packet to the queue, I get another 1460 bytes of data.  If the strings are their maximum length, and I'm downloading 60 strings, 5 packets will be enough to capture everything.

1. If I add more packets than necessary to the read queue, and most reads only use one packet, will I eventually overflow the packet queue?  Can I apply some sort of timeout to wipeout unused packets?  There is no way for the app to predict how may packets will be required for any given read event.

Another problem is that the last minute of a packet's data string will inevitably be split over two packets.  What I'd like to do is collect all of the packets' NSData instances, concatenate them into one large NSData instance, convert that to a string, and parse that string as normal.

1. How will I know when the last packet that is going to be received for a given read request has been received, so that I can combine the NSDatas and parse the resulting string?
   Each minute's string ends with an exclamation mark '!', but there is no unique symbol to denote the end of a transmission.  I assume the same timeout that solves problem 1 will solve problem 2.

This app is already published for Android.  So if at all possible, I'd like to avoid changing the server and Android code to accomodate the iOS version.

Comment: What IP protocol are you using?  If it's TCP, what protocol on top of TCP are you using?  I don't understand that stuff about only getting 15 mins of data when the server is sending 60 mins. When the server has sent all the data, does it disconnect the client?

Comment: Never mind - if you're using GCDAsyncSocket, it's TCP. 1460 looks suspiciously like ethernet MTU size.  A horrible thought has just occurred to me - are you assuming that TCP transfers messages larger than one byte?

Comment: I'm sending strings of data using TCP.  I'm using National Instruments' Labwindows on the PC application to create a TCP server.  When the server connects, It creates the string and sends it using a Labwindows library function ServerTCPWrite().  The packetization is abstracted from me on the PC side.  But when I do a read on the app side, GDCAS is giving me one packet of data.  Thats because GDCAS is only placing one packet on the readQueue per write request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just adding 5 packets to the readQueue every time I request a read, and add attach a timeout to the reads, so that the queue doesn't overflow.  I also set up a NSTimer to fire after 2 seconds at the end of the didReadData callback.  When the timer elapses, it is assumed that all data available has been read, and the strings are processed.  Each timer is using the same NSTimer instance, so if the timer is active, and another didReadData event occurs, a new timer is started, wiping out the old timer.